# How not to delete default image when new one is uploaded?

Tags: django

I wrote code that deletes old user avatar when user uploads new one. And the problem is that, if user has default avatar and decides to change it, default image gets deleted.

Here is my code:

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=Profile)
def delete_file_on_change(sender, instance, **kwargs):
if instance.pk:
    try:
        old_image = Profile.objects.get(pk=instance.pk).image
    except Profile.DoesNotExist:
        return
    new_image = instance.image
    if old_image and old_image.url != new_image.url:
        old_image.delete(save=False)
```

I tried this:

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=Profile)
def delete_file_on_change(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if instance.image.url == '/media/default.jpg':
        ...
```

But it didn't work because `print(instance.image.url)` for some reason, returns not `/media/default.jpg`
but url of newly uploaded file.

Also, here's my view:

```
def update_user(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if 'edit_profile' in request.POST:
            profile_form = UpdateProfileForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES, instance=request.user.profile)
            if profile_form.is_valid():
                profile_form.save()
                return redirect('editprofile')
    profile_form = UpdateProfileForm(instance=request.user.profile)
    context = {'ps_form': password_form, 'u_form': user_info_form, 'pr_form': profile_form}
    return render(request, 'update_user.html', context=context)
```

Answer (score 0):

May be before deleting an old image just check if an image url is not the default one.

#### Example

```py
if old_image and old_image.url not in (new_image.url, '/media/default.jpg'):
        old_image.delete(save=False)
```

#### or

```py
if old_image and old_image.url != new_image.url and old_image.url != '/media/default.jpg':
        old_image.delete(save=False)
```

Be sure to check the path of your default image

Comment: Thank you! I will reply later when i try it out